# An inequality involving $n$ blue points and $n$ red points on a line.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, geometric-inequalities

**Question** : Let $n$ blue points $A_i$ and $n$ red points $B_i$ ($i=1,2,...,n$) be situated on a line. Prove that $$\sum_{i,j}A_iB_j\ge \sum_{i<j}A_iA_j+\sum_{i<j}B_iB_j$$

I tried inducting on $n$ but cant proceed in the inductive step ( as usual ). Please help, if there is a direct method of approach please give hints. Is this true if all the blue points were on a different line?

Comment: Probably break it down into triangles and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Well in the original problem all points are on a line.

Comment: Three points on a line still make a triangle, at least as far as the triangle inequality is concerned. In fact, if you want the triangle inequality to give _equality_, the three points _have_ to be on a line (and in the right order).

Comment: Well I tried triangle inequality but don't found a way out, please help. Thanks.

Comment: A question is an one-dimensional version of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385354/an-inequality-about-the-sum-of-distances-between-points-same-color-le-diffe) question, so I vote to close it as a  duplicate.