# Sum of distance between integer numbers

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality, network

Let $p$ is a positive integer, and let $A_1,\ldots,A_p$ be a partition of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. My conjecture is that
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^p\left( \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{a_i,a_j \in A_p}|a_i-a_j|}{|A_p|} \right)\leq \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n}|i-j|}{n}=\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{3}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
I have checked that this is true for $n=4,5,6$. I have tried to prove this conjecture by induction, but I did not succeed yet. I think also about the weighted network. The sum $\displaystyle\sum_{a_i,a_j \in A_p}|a_i-a_j|$ is the sum of the inverse of *closeness* of all points in network represented by $A_p$. But once again, I did not find any good references.

Another way I have thought about the proof is as follows.

Let $A,B$ be two disjoint sets of positive integers. The conjecture above is true if we can prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{a_i,a_j \in A}|a_i-a_j|}{|A|}+\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{b_i,b_j \in B}|b_i-b_j|}{|B|}\leq \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{x_i,x_j \in A\cup B}|x_i-x_j|}{|A|+|B|}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
I am trying to prove inequality (2) by proving that if we move one element from set $B$ to set $A$, then it will increase the sum in LHS of (2) provided that $|A|\geq |B|$.

I am still working on it. If you have any ideas, comments, or even counter examples, please do not hesitate to write them here. Thank you very much.

Update: The inequality in (2) seems wrong. I have done a simulation for the case $n=10$. The values of those partitions are not monotone; however, they're all smaller than $\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{3}$.

Comment: Can you edit in a specific counterexample to equation (2)?

Comment: Your indices conflict.  I think you meant $\sum_{k=1}^p$ instead of $\sum_{i=1}^p$ and $A_k$ instead of $A_p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality (2) is true. Moreover, it holds for any two nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of real numbers.
The respective claim can be proved similarly to the proof of the first part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385354/an-inequality-about-the-sum-of-distances-between-points-same-color-le-diffe/2378522#2378522)
answer. At the final step, suppose that we have $a$ numbers from $A$ and $b$ numbers from $B$ equal to $−1$ and $|A|-a$ numbers from $A$ and $|B|-b$ numbers from $B$ equal to $1$. Then
the difference between the right-hand and the left-hand sides of the inequality is
$$\frac{2(a+b)(|A|+|B|-a-b)}{|A|+|B|}-\frac{2a(|A|-a)}{|A|}-$$ $$\frac{2b(|B|-b)}{|B|}=\frac{2(|A|b-|B|a)^2}{|A|\cdot |B|\cdot |A+B|}\ge 0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.